# How to use direction arrow key on colab when I use mobile devices?

Tags: ipad, google-colaboratory

Recently, I’ve spent a reasonably large amount of time using google colab to do my programming. I found it is really useful and light weight, thus I bought an iPad Pro keyboard to do mobile programming, but surprisingly, the colab cell did not work with iPad keyboard arrow key, that makes me unable to use it to program. Any suggestion to fix this issue? Any one ever trying to use iPad keyboard with google colab?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/113

The underlying iOS issue: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149054

Comment: Any fix so far?

Comment: Seems like a bit of a fudge, Jupyter notebooks on Azure work fine with arrow keys on iOS.